# Using window.location.assign causes Meteor.userId to be lost

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm writing a Meteor site where the client routing is done by angular-meteor and the server routing is done by IronRouter. One of the calls requires that after a browser operation, I call a server side route so I'm using:

```
window.location.assign('/my/server/route')
```

Rather than the Angular $location.path(...) (because there is no client side route for this url)

I've noticed that if the user is logged in, then after calling window.location.assign, `Meteor.userId` becomes null on the server side.

From my logs - Before .assign (client and server side):

```
Meteor.userId: iaPkB6cxKGMS7b7H6
```

After assign (server side)

```
Meteor.userId: null
```

Can someone explain why the userId is lost when this happens?

Comment: It seems to be the case that Meteor is not using cookies to store the userId so the only way it can be accessed is using Meteor javascript in the browser, or in a Meteor.call (which must pass userId to the server some how). http://info.meteor.com/blog/session-cookies